# how to set multi data from checkbox in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, mapping

here in my code i have 5 checkboxes that i want to push their values if they were checked but when i tick a checkbox and then tick another one an error displayes that says **TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null**

and this is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Label from '../../styles/Label';

function AlertReminder() {
  const [selectedReminders, setSelectedReminders] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(selectedReminders);
  }, [selectedReminders]);

  const remindersList = '1 hour before,12 hour before,24 hour before,48 hour before,1 week ago'.split(',');
  console.log(remindersList);
  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    if (selectedReminders.includes(e.target.value)) {
      selectedReminders.splice(selectedReminders.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
      console.log(selectedReminders);
    } else {
      setSelectedReminders(selectedReminders => [...selectedReminders, e.target.value]);
      console.log(selectedReminders);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Label>Alert Reminders:</Label>

      <form>

        {
        remindersList.map(
          (c) => (
            <label>
              {c}
              <input type="checkbox" value={c} onChange={changeHandler} />
            </label>
          )
        )
      }
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AlertReminder;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses synthetic events, it is gone by the time you are trying to use it in if/else statement.

There are three solutions:

1. To have it persist you need to begin your changeHandler with `e.persist()` (just add it after `const changeHandler = (e) => {`).
2. Begin changeHandler with `const target = e.target` and than use `target` instead of `e.target`.
3. Begin changeHandler with `const value = e.target.value` and than use `value` instead of `e.target.value` [working code (sandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-sara-wqi00?file=/src/App.js).

More on this in [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).
Note, in React 17 you will be used `e.target.value` as expected ([release notes](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#no-event-pooling)).

Comment: No problem, this might not be needed in the future releases React 17 https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#no-event-pooling